# Doxygen Java multiple interfaces diagram

Tags: java, interface, doxygen, graphviz

I'm trying to generate documentation for an Android projet with [Doxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen).

I use [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) to generate a collaboration diagram, but I can't find how to have multiple interface in the graph!

```
public class ImageProcessing extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Camera.PreviewCallback, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
```

With the previous class declaration, I obtain a graph with only Activity and first interface OnClickListener.

How can I declare that they must consider other interfaces too?

Answer (score 0):

It works alright for me.

Maybe you need to select EXTRACT_ALL.